# How to update text value on the fly from another input

Tags: flutter, dart

first time using Flutter for mobile the project.
How to change the text value on the fly when an input field is typing?

Example the default value display in the text is `0.00`. Now user key in the number `1` then text value shall change to `1` immediately.

Here is my display Text

```
              Consumer<Settings>(
                builder: (context, settings, child) => Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: <Widget>[

                    Text(
                      'TOTAL ${_getGrandTotal(_formData.items)}',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

My inputformfield

```
            Consumer<Settings>(
                builder: (context, settings, child) => Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          initialValue: _formData.total ?? '0.00',
                          decoration: TextFormField.decoration(
                            labelText: Localizations.of(context)
                                .text('label_total'),
                          ),
                          onChanged: (String value) async {
                          _getGrandTotal(value);

                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `StatefulWidget` and then use `setState(() {})` inside the `onChanged` of the `TextFormField`. Like this:

```
TextFormField(
    initialValue: _formData.total ?? '0.00',
    decoration: TextFormField.decoration(
        labelText: Localizations.of(context).text('label_total'),
    ),
    onChanged: (String value) {
        setState(() {
          _formData.total = value;
        });
    },
),
```

The `setState` will then cause a rebuild of your widget and also render the up-to-date value.